# Display a Search bar on header on scroll HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, searchbar

I have a search bar which would like to display onto the header on scroll, a great example is like the one on this site: https://www.indiamart.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1 -** A simple way to do this would be to detect a scroll & add and remove a class that contains `display: none`;

You can have an event listener -

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   if( window.scrollY !== 0) {
            
      document.getElementById('searchBar').classList.add('scrolled');
   } else {
            
      document.getElementById('searchBar').classList.remove('scrolled');
   }
});
```

With the CSS -

```
.noScroll
{
    background: yellow;
    position:fixed;
    height: 50px; /*Whatever you want*/
    width: 100%; /*Whatever you want*/
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}

/*Use this class when you want your content to be shown after some scroll*/
.scrolled
{
  display: block !important;
}

.parent {
  /* something to ensure that the parent container is scrollable */
  height: 200vh;
}
```

And the html would be -

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class ='noScroll' id='searchBar'>Content you want to show on scroll</div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the same - https://jsfiddle.net/kecnrh3g/

**Approach 2 -**
Another simple approach would be

```
<script>
let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById('searchBar').style.top = '-50px';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('searchBar').style.top = '0';
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>
```

with the html -

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id ='searchBar'>Content you want to show on scroll</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#searchBar {
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.parent {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the same - https://jsfiddle.net/0tkedcns/1/

Answer (score 0):

From the same example, the idea is only to show/hide once user scroll the page using inline css `display` property, you can do the same or at least provide a code sample so we can help you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="search-bar">
    <div class="sticky-search">
        Sticky Search: <input type="text" value="search" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sticky-search {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background:blue;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var searchHeight = $(".search-bar").outerHeight();
var offset = $(".search-bar").offset().top;
var totalHeight = searchHeight + offset;

console.log(totalHeight);
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= totalHeight) {
        $('.sticky-search').show();
    } else {
        $('.sticky-search').hide();
    }
});
```